# c++ Unpacking parameter pack from template arguments

Tags: c++, parameters, pack

How to achieve want I want below?  The paramater pack I want to unpack is not in a function argument list but template argument list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

const std::size_t SIZE = 10;

template <int...ARGS>
std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b;
    // I want to set b[n] = true, where n takes on all values from ARGS...
    // what to put in here???
    return b;
}

// Example of what I want to achieve:
int main() {
    const std::array<bool, SIZE> b = func<1,3,7>();
    // I want b[1]==true, b[3]==true, b[7]==true, all others false
    for (int x: b) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

I have to use this form for func (instead of func(1,3,7)) to get my bigger program working (I'm dealing with multiple inheritance issues).

Comment: you should specify C++ standard, since this changes level of complexity of the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recursive template solution:

```
// recursive helper struct
template <int n, int First, int ...Rest>
struct helper {
  static void funcImpl(std::array<bool, SIZE>& temp) {
    temp[First] = true;
    helper<n - 1, Rest...>::funcImpl(temp);
  }
};

// partial specialization to catch base case
template <int First>
struct helper<0, First> {
  static void funcImpl(std::array<bool, SIZE>& temp) {
    temp[First] = true;
  }
};

template <int ...Args>
std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b = {}; // 0 inititalize array
    helper<sizeof...(Args) - 1, Args...>::funcImpl(b);
    return b;
}
```

**EDIT:** A super simplified version inspired by iavr's solution:

```
template <int... A>
std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b = {};
    auto values = {A...};
    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](int n){b[n] = true;});
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The last solution is simply beautiful.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a much simpler solution that requires nothing extra, just this:

```
struct _do { template <typename... T> _do(T&&...) { } };

template <int... A>
std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b = {};
    _do{b[A] = true...};
    return b;
}
```

This assumes the array is first initialized and then populated. My previous solution computed all values at compile time and directly initialized the array with them. So this is probably faster to compile and slower to run.

Comment: This potentially most elegant solution sets the true values correct, but the remaining are not set to false.  I initialized as you suggested:  std::array<bool, SIZE> b = {false};  b = func<1,3,7>();

Comment: It now works if change to std::array<bool, SIZE> b = {}; in func definition

Comment: @prestokeys I really thought that since `std::array` is an aggregate type, its elements are default-initialized. Anyhow, I've changed initialization to `b = {};`, thanks.

Comment: Nice clean and works with C++11: https://godbolt.org/z/K4sKabz5v

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, you can use *fold expressions*:

```cpp
template <std::size_t... ARGS>
constexpr std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b{};
    ((b[ARGS] = true), ...);    // fold expression
    return b;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j5nbTxPsq)

---

For C++11 and 14, I'd prefer using an unnamed lambda, like this:

```cpp
template <std::size_t... ARGS>
std::array<bool, SIZE> func() {
    std::array<bool, SIZE> b{};
    [](...){}(b[ARGS] = true...);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38e0682d8c446367).

Here's the implementation of `func`:

```
template <int... A, int... N>
std::array<bool, sizeof...(N)>
func(sizes <N...>)
{
    return std::array<bool, sizeof...(N)>{{in <N, A...>()...}};
}

template <int... A>
std::array<bool, SIZE>
func() { return func <A...>(range <SIZE>()); }
```

where `sizes` represents an `int` sequence, `range <S>` constructs sequence `0,...,S-1` and `in<N, A...>()` checks whether number `N` is in sequence `A...` (definitions in the live example).

This not the most efficient (compile-wise) way to implement, because for every element of `N...` we need to scan pack `A...`. It's better to scan packs `A...`, `L...` in parallel, with a modification of function `in()`. But anyway this was more straightforward to think of and write down.

Comment: Perhaps not the fastest at compile-time, but the ability to initialise arrays in a `constexpr` way (which either this or a very similar pattern would do) can be invaluable. +1